# ¿Cómo ejecutar public void onBackPressed en un BottomBar?

Tags: java, android, bottombar, onbackpressed

Tengo un `BottomBar` con 5 botones (5 fragments) y tengo puesto que cuando pulse atrás vaya al primer `fragment` (más abajo en el código está). El problema que tengo es que no siempre quiero eso, quiero que cuando esté seleccionado el 4º `fragment` y pulses atrás, vayas al 4º `fragment` de nuevo y no al 1º, **¿ cómo ?** No puedo poner la función de `onBackPressed` en ningún fragment tampoco....

Código:

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

BottomBar mBottomBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }

    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int i) {


            if (i == R.id.one) {

                First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f1).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.two) {

                Second_fragment f2 = new Second_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f2).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.three) {

                Three_fragment f3 = new Three_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f3).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.four) {

                Four_fragment f4 = new Four_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f4).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.five) {
                Map_fragment f5 = new Map_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f5).commit();
               // startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity1.this, MapActivity.class));



            }

        }

    });

    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, "#c92029");

    // seems this is  working to highlist tab
    mBottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(0, true);


    // Loading first Fragment to FrameLayout manually
    First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f1).commit();


}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
   First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f1).commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posibilidad es guardar en una variable en que fragmento te encuentras y dependiendo de este pues vas un fragmento u otro :

```
BottomBar mBottomBar;
int currentFragment = 0;

//....

            if (i == R.id.one) {

              First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f1).commit();

              currentFragment  = 1;
            }

            if (i == R.id.two) {

              Second_fragment f2 = new Second_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f2).commit();

              currentFragment  = 2;
            }  

//....

 public void onBackPressed() {

  Fragment fragment = null;

   switch(currentFragment){

     case 1:// si estoy en el fragment 1 voy al 2            
        fragment = new Second_fragment();
        break;
     case 2:// si estoy en el fragment 2 voy al 1   
        fragment = new First_fragment();
        break;
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment ).commit();

 }
```

Comment: La linea de bajo no iba y he tenido que subirla pero sí ha ido :) +1

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de hacer esto es implementar un interface de comunicación entre el Activity y el Fragment o Fragments indicados.

Para ello en el Activity creas el interface y los métodos para asignar y eliminar los objetos que escucharán cuando se pulse el botón de atrás:

```
// .... 
ArrayList<OnBackButtonPressedListener> backListenerList = new ArrayList<>();

public interface OnBackButtonPressedListener {
    void atrasPresionado();
}

public addOnBackButtonPressedListener (OnBackButtonPressedListener backListener) {
    backListenerList.add(backListener);
}

public removeBackButtonPressedListener (OnBackButtonPressedListener backListener) {
    backListenerList.remove(backListener);
}
// ....
```

En el método `onBackPressed()` compruebas si hay algún `listener` activo, en ese caso le notificas que se ha pulsado el botón de atrás:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(backListenerList != null && backListenerList.size() > 0){
        for(OnBackButtonPressedListener backListener : backListenerList){
            backListener.atrasPresionado();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego en el Fragment simplemente implementas el interface y en el `onAttach` lo añades a la lista del Activity mediante el método `addOnBackButtonPressedListener` creado antes.

En el método generado al implementar el interfaz (`atrasPresionado()`) haces lo que desees.

No olvides eliminar el `listener` en el `onDetach` del Fragment mediante el método `removeBackButtonPressedListener`.

El hecho de crear una lista es por si necesitas comunicación con varios Fragment, si sólo va a ser uno no necesitas la lista.