# ¿Cómo refrescar un fragment al presionar un botón en una activity?

Tags: android

Tengo un `fragment` en el cual tengo un `ratingBar` , al dar estrellas en el `ratingBar` se llama una `activiy` en el cual lleno unos datos, en la `activity` hay un botón de aceptar, la idea es que al presionar aceptar, me salga del `activity` y me devuelva al `fragment` donde tengo el `ratingBar` asignando estos datos a los componentes del `fragment`.
¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Este es mi `fragment`

```
public class FacilityDetailFragment extends Fragment{

public FacilityDetailFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facility_detail, container, false);

    ratingBarNewReview = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ratingNewReviewUser);


    //aqui llamo al activity
    ratingBarNewReview.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), UserReviewActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

    ratingBarNewReview.setRating(0);


    return rootView;
}
```

este es mi `activity`

```
public void update(final String facilityId){
    new GetFacilityReviewsAsyncTask(new FacilityReviewsAsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final ArrayList<FacilityReview> facilityReviews) {
            reviews = new String[facilityReviews.size()];
            userNames = new String[facilityReviews.size()];
            images = new String[facilityReviews.size()];
            totalLikes = new int[facilityReviews.size()];
            totalDeslikes = new int[facilityReviews.size()];
            rating = new int[facilityReviews.size()];

            //aqui cargo los datos
            for (int i=0;i<facilityReviews.size();i++){

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_review, null);

                reviews[i] = facilityReviews.get(i).getReview();
                userNames[i] = facilityReviews.get(i).getReviewer().getRealName();
                images[i] = facilityReviews.get(i).getReviewer().getProfilePicture();
                totalLikes[i] = facilityReviews.get(i).getTotalLikes();
                totalDeslikes[i] = facilityReviews.get(i).getTotalDeslikes();
                rating[i] = facilityReviews.get(i).getRating();

                final TextView lblId = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblId);
                ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
                ImageButton btnLike = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnLikeReview);
                ImageButton btnDeslike = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDeslikeReview);
                TextView review = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblReview);
                review.setText(reviews[i]);
                final TextView lblTotalLikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTotalLikes);
                lblTotalLikes.setText(String.valueOf(totalLikes[i]));
                RatingBar ratingBarReview =(RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.listitemrating);
                ratingBarReview.setRating(Float.valueOf(rating[i]));

                final TextView lblTotalDeslikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTotalDeslikes);
                lblTotalDeslikes.setText(String.valueOf(totalDeslikes[i]));

                if(!(jwt != "" && refreshToken != "")){
                    btnLike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    btnDeslike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    lblTotalLikes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    lblTotalDeslikes.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                });
        }
    }).execute(facilityId);
}
```

Comment: Donde cargas FacilityDetailFragment , cual boton es el que deseas usar?

Comment: La mejor forma de hacer esto es usar un interface, en la documentación oficial lo tienes para comunicación entre Fragments pero es exactamente lo mismo sólo que desde tu Activity https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html Te dejo también el enlace a otro ejemplo que hice para otra pregunta pero que te serviría como orientación http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32485/c%c3%b3mo-ejecutar-public-void-onbackpressed-en-un-bottombar/32536#32536

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar un `startActivityForResult` para recibir una dato al finalizar un activity:

[startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=es)

Aquí un ejemplo:

Esto es para lanzar la actividad desde el Fragment

```
static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;  
// The request code
...
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}
```

Este método va en el Fragment que llamo al Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.
            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

Este código es para terminar la Activity con datos de retorno

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(); returnIntent.putExtra("result",result); setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent); finish();
```